# Run VBA with MSGBox on a password protected File

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run the code as described here:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim rr As Range, r As Range
    Dim bNo As Boolean
    Set rr = Range("AU17:AU300").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    bNo = False
    For Each r In rr
        If r.Value = "No" Then
             bNo = True
        End If
    Next r

    If bNo = True Then
       MsgBox "The HS Number entered is not recorded. Please call Marcelo", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

on a password protected file.

I get

> runtime error 1004: You cannot use this command on a protected sheet.

in Line: `Set rr = Range...`

Is there a way to bypass this as I can't leave the worksheet unprotected.

Comment: Linking to a different code is not sufficient here. Please include the *exact code **you** actually use* within your question ([edit]) and tell in which code line you get the error.

Comment: Which line is flagged when the error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Don't protect your worksheets manually. Instead protect them with VBA using `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`. This way your worksheets are protected for the user interface but VBA can still access them:

```
.Protect Password:="myPassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

Note that you need to reapply `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` after reopening the workbook.

Comment: Hi Peh, thank you for your answer. I'll try it and let you know if it solved my Problem.